# How to disable injection of all polyfills (except regeneratorRuntime) when using babel-preset-env?

Tags: babeljs, babel-polyfill

I'm using Babel 6's [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-env) to compile code targeted at IE10+.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["ie >= 10"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-3",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

But I'm also, separately, polyfilling the browser (using Polyfill.io) before my Babel-compiled app script runs. So I don't want babel-preset-env to inject any polyfills for modern JS APIs (`Promise`, `Array.from`, etc), as I've already polyfilled these, so it's a waste of bytes.

I still want babel-preset-env to compile any modern *syntax* down to IE10, just not to inject polyfills. But I *do* want it to inject `regeneratorRuntime` – this is not really a polyfill, but rather a helper utility that supports Babel's approach for transforming the *syntax* of async functions and generators down to IE10-compatible code. Not sure if this complicates it.

I know babel-preset-env has a [`useBuiltIns` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins) (aside: I don't understand name of this option), which apparently lets you specify *how* you want it to add polyfills... but I'm not clear on how to tell it *not* to add polyfills at all (except regeneratorRuntime, if it counts that as a polyfill – not sure).

Is there a way to do that?